# Flutter App open Linked In App through url lancher package

Tags: flutter, linkedin-api

What is the link which can I use in '''url_launcher''' package in Flutter to open a LinkedIn app from my Flutter app?

Answer (score 2):

The URL is https://www.linkedin.com/

The following is an example implementation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _launchURL,
        child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I pass some text to post something on LinkedIn?